# npm gulp 800a138f javascript error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

When i put 'gulp hello' in cmd i got this error 800a138f javascript object expected error

## This is my package.json file

```
`{
 "name": "goes",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node gulp.js"
 },
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1"
  }
 }`
```

## This is gulp.js

```
 `var gulp = require('gulp');
 gulp.task('hello', function() {
 console.log('Hello Zell');
 });`
```